# How to find $c$ and $d$ from the equation $(c+id)^2=1$?

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

I need to solve this complex equation:
$$
(c + id)^2 = 1
$$

where $i^2=-1$.

What am I supposed to calculate here? Just $c$ and $d$?

Comment: Yes, $c$ and $d$ need to be identified.

Comment: Are $c$ and $d$ complex numbers? Or are they the real and imaginary parts of $z$ in $z^2 = 1$?

Comment: Nothing noted, but I guess they are the real and imaginary parts of a complex number z.  I calculated c = +- 1/di  and d = +- (-i) - c/i...is this correct or am I messing up something?

Comment: Hem, what else than $c$ and $d$ are there to be computed ??

Comment: OP: Watch out the solutions you accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(c+id)^2=1 \Rightarrow c^2+2cdi+i^2d^2=1 \Rightarrow c^2+2cdi-d^2=1 \Rightarrow (c^2-d^2)+2cdi=1+0i$$

The real part of the LHS must be equal to the real part of the RHS and the imaginary part of the LHS must equal to the imaginary part of the RHS.

So, you have to solve the following system  : $$c^2-d^2=1 \\ 2cd=0$$

---

From the first equation we get $c^2=1+d^2$.

Substituting this in $2cd=0 \Rightarrow cd=0 \Rightarrow c^2d^2=0$ we get $$(1+d^2)d^2=0 \\ \Rightarrow 1+d^2=0 \text{ or } d^2=0 \\ \Rightarrow d^2=-1 \ \ \text{ or } \ \ d=0 \\ \Rightarrow d=\pm i \ \ \text{ or } \ \ d=0$$

For $d=\pm i$, substituting at $c^2=1+d^2$ we get $c^2=0 \Rightarrow c=0$.

For $d=0$, substistuting at  we get $c^2=1 \Rightarrow c=\pm 1$.

Comment: Then I calculate d = 0 and get c = +/- 1?

Comment: I added more details in my answer... @user284003

Comment: I see, missed some parts here...thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome!! @user284003

Comment: Funny, this (accepted) answer is the only one which proposes two wrong solutions. No, (c,d)=(0,±i) are **not** acceptable solutions.

Answer (score 4):

By far, the simplest solution is simply to take the square root of both sides:

$c+di = \pm 1$

which allows us to immediately equate real and imaginary parts to get $c = \pm 1, d = 0$.

Much simpler than squaring the LHS.

Answer (score 2):

Your post says $i^2=1$, surely you mean $i^2=-1$ the complex unit, no?

Well assuming $i^2=-1$, firstly
$$(c+id)^{2}=(c+id)(c+id)$$

After multiplying we find
$$c^{2}+2icd+(id)^{2}=1$$
Since $i^{2}=-1$
$$c^{2}-d^{2}+2icd=1$$
Since $1$ is real and there is no imaginary part on the r.h.s we can split to two equations
\begin{align}
c^{2}-d^{2} &= 1 \\
cd          &= 0
\end{align}
Two equations in two unknowns, can you take it form here?

Best,
Bacon.

**EDIT**
In response to your comment below (I don't have sufficient reputation to make a comment yet) I would say that in order for the product of two quantities to be identically zero, at *least one* needs to be zero. Therefore using this fact and the difference of two squares observation above it, you have several cases to consider before you find the values of $c$ and $d$.

Comment: ARO \o/ (sorry, I had to...)

Comment: Aaah ok, thats what I did, but I didn't know that the real part has to be equal to 1 and the imaginary part has to be equal to 0. Thanks for that, but I am stuck again..if I calculate c and d from the second equation they are both 0? And filling them in the first equation doesn't help?  And yeah, sorry 'i' is the complex unit.

Comment: @user284003 When solving these types of problems it is best to keep an eye on the real and imaginary parts as two complex quantities are only equal if and only if their real and imaginary parts are respectively equal. The second part is solving a quadratic simultaneous equation which can almost always be split into cases.

Comment: So if I calculate 2cd = 0 -> d = 0. Then c² -0 = 1 -> c = +/- 1. So the answer would be c = +/- 1 and d would be 0? Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

From the fundamental theorem of algebra, you know that the equation $z^2=1$, a quadratic one, has at most two roots.

One of the roots is the obvious $z=1$, and with a few seconds of thinking, $z=-1$ is the other.

Answer (score 0):

By the binomial formulas we know that 
$$
0=z^2-1=(z-1)(z+1)
$$
has the only solutions $z=\pm 1$. This is true in the real numbers and stays true in the field of complex numbers.

Comment: When you say 'by the binomial formulas' do you mean just factoring the polynomial?

Comment: Yes. $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$. And a factorization into linear factors is unique for polynomials over a field (or generally UFD).

Answer (score -2):

First of all i would observe $$1 = e^{i2k\pi} \;\; k \in \mathbb{Z}$$ then i would write $(a + ib)^2 = \left( \rho e^{i\theta} \right)^2 = \rho^2 e^{i2\theta}$ so...

$$\rho^2 e^{i2\theta} = e^{i2k\pi}$$ which of course implies that $\rho = 1$, (since it is a positive real number) while

$$ 2\theta = 2 k \pi \Rightarrow \theta = k \pi$$

So the solutions are of the form

$$a + ib = e^{ik\pi}$$ which implies for $k$ even 
$$a + ib = 1 \Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{l} a = 1 \\ b = 0 \end{array} \right.$$

while for $k$ odd

$$a + ib = -1 \Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{l} a = -1 \\ b = 0 \end{array} \right.$$

Comment: At the level OP is at I doubt eulers formula will be helpful.

Comment: The euler formula is helpful to understand where the solutions of $z^n = 1$ belong... i think it could be useful, also... i don't have to solve any quadratic system.

Comment: Yes but do you think that the OP will understand eulers formula? Clearly by the question posed he is not at that level.

Comment: (what does OP stand for?)

Comment: Original poster.